# Span single transaction over several sequential psql sessions

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am running [PostgreSQL 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/index.html) database server and [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html) terminal front-end on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) 10.04 Lucid Lynx and would like to span a single transaction over several sequential psql sessions.

When I connect to my database with psql a new connection is established and a server backend process for this connection is created. When I disconnect the connection is released and the backend process terminates. A (non-XA*) transaction is bound to the scope of a connection, so obviously there is no straight forward way to span a single transaction over several psql sessions.

What I would like to achieve is that the following sequence of commands can be run within a single transaction and therefore return the same transaction timestamp on each call of `now()`:

```
tscho@test:~$ sudo -u postgres psql -p 5433 --no-align --tuples-only -c "select now()"
2012-02-17 21:25:07.027056+01
tscho@test:~$ sudo -u postgres psql -p 5433 --no-align --tuples-only -c "select now()"
2012-02-17 21:25:09.487601+01
```

database log:

```
2012-02-17 21:25:07 CET 0- LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2012-02-17 21:25:07 CET 0- LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
2012-02-17 21:25:07 CET 0-2/0 LOG:  duration: 0.366 ms  statement: select now()
2012-02-17 21:25:07 CET 0- LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.002 user=postgres database=postgres host=[local]
2012-02-17 21:25:09 CET 0- LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2012-02-17 21:25:09 CET 0- LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
2012-02-17 21:25:09 CET 0-2/0 LOG:  duration: 0.347 ms  statement: select now()
2012-02-17 21:25:09 CET 0- LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.002 user=postgres database=postgres host=[local]
```

Clearly this is not what I *really* want to do. I want to be able to execute several bash scripts that connect to the database and execute SQL statements and scripts with psql within a single transaction.

* Afaik the XA protocol would allow BEGIN TRANSACTION and PREPARE TRANSACTION on different connections but PostgreSQL does not support this.

---

My first shot to solve this problem was to setup the [PgBouncer 1.5](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer/) connection pool and configure it as a simple proxy with exactly one connection to the target database (session pooling mode). My reasoning was that PgBouncer would establish this connection at start-up and that I can then connect/disconnect to/from the proxy with psql while the connection to the database keeps open.

```
tscho@test:~$ sudo -u postgres psql pgproxy -U pgbouncer -p 6432 --no-align --tuples-only -c "select now()"
2012-02-17 21:25:23.517019+01
tscho@test:~$ sudo -u postgres psql pgproxy -U pgbouncer -p 6432 --no-align --tuples-only -c "select now()"
2012-02-17 21:25:26.943172+01
```

This actually works out quite well as the database log shows:

```
2012-02-17 21:25:17 CET 0- LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2012-02-17 21:25:17 CET 0- LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
2012-02-17 21:25:23 CET 0-1/0 LOG:  duration: 0.110 ms  statement: select 1
2012-02-17 21:25:23 CET 0-1/0 LOG:  duration: 0.053 ms  statement: select now()
2012-02-17 21:25:23 CET 0-1/0 LOG:  duration: 0.046 ms  statement: DISCARD ALL
2012-02-17 21:25:26 CET 0-1/0 LOG:  duration: 0.126 ms  statement: select now()
2012-02-17 21:25:26 CET 0-1/0 LOG:  duration: 0.043 ms  statement: DISCARD ALL
```

But there is a *little* problem with this approach, as soon as I begin a transaction on the proxy connection and disconnect...

```
tscho@test:~$ sudo -u postgres psql pgproxy -U pgbouncer -p 6432 --no-align --tuples-only -c "start transaction"
START TRANSACTION
```

...the connection is released by PgBouncer.

```
2012-02-17 21:32:47 CET 0-1/2178 LOG:  duration: 0.025 ms  statement: start transaction
2012-02-17 21:32:47 CET 0- LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:20.737 user=postgres database=postgres host=[local]
```

Of course this makes perfect sense for a connection pool. Its job is to provide (a) shared connection(s) for several clients but to isolate the transactions of these clients. But for my use case a shared transaction is exactly what I would need...

So my question is now, is there a way to configure PgBouncer (or another connection pool) to **not** release the connection upon disconnection after BEGIN/START TRANSACTION or is there another way to achieve what I would like to do?

All further questions to this post, comments and of course answers appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it would be easiest to run a psql in the background, with it set to execute stdin, and connect its stdin to a named pipe. Then you can continually push data into that pipe, and finally push "end; \quit". Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

psql_pipe=/tmp/psql$$
mkfifo -m 600 $psql_pipe
psql < $psql_pipe &
exec 3>$psql_pipe
psql_pid=$!

echo "> Started psql (pid=$psql_pid) reading from $psql_pipe"
trap '
  kill $psql_pid
  rm -f $psql_pipe
' EXIT

echo "begin;" >&3

echo "select now();" >&3

sleep 2

echo "select now();" >&3

sleep 2

echo "end; \quit" >&3

wait $psql_pid
```

Note that you can't simply do `echo "sql" >$psql_pipe` since the EOF would be transmitted to psql, which would then exit early-- the shell script has to keep its fd open.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer, this works like a charm! The named pipe is the proxy I was looking for, I just don't connect with psql but with echo ;)

Comment: Rather than using a named pipe, use a coprocess if possible. That'll help ensure you won't get file conflicts, tempfile security vulnerabilities, write-permission issues, etc, and will make sure your psql processes get cleaned up when your shell exits. See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/398670

Comment: @CraigRinger nice, I'd never met the `coproc` command before

Answer (score 5):

I usually tackle this a bit differently: I collect up the SQL files/snippets I want to run and then execute a single psql session that issues a BEGIN then uses \i to include each file in turn, finally issuing a COMMIT. Eg (untested but the general idea):

```
psql -1 <<__END__
\i script1.sql
\i script2.sql
\i script3.sql
__END__

errstatus=$?
if ! $errstatus; then
  echo "psql failed with $errstatus"
  exit 1
fi
```

Edit: Alternately, if your script and PostgreSQL session need two-way interaction, say if you're generating dynamic sql, then you can either use a co-process or use a more sophisticated scripting language than sh that has its own built-in PostgreSQL interface. See [this answer I wrote to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/398670) a while ago.

I use Python and psycopg for this sort of thing most of the time, but a coprocess can be useful if you're stuck with bash.

If you're on Windows and using `cmd.exe` then (a) I'm sorry and (b) you'll have to use a real scripting language or, if PowerShell supports anything like co-processes, maybe use PowerShell and psql.

Comment: And this is much simpler and much more reliable than messing with connection poolers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If it was just about executing several static SQL scripts in a single transaction of course this would be the appropriate solution. But the bash scripts I want to run generate dynamic SQL statements and queries depending on parameters and user input. I cannot just include them because e.g. the input to the second script depends on the outcome of the first script.

Comment: @Tometzky Please note my comment to this answer. I am not keen on messing around with a connection pooler either, I am just looking for a clean solution to my requirement, and the connection pooler was my first shot. I am not planning to use this on a production database right now ;)

Comment: @tscho: You could reverse the stuff: Call parts of your shell script FROM psql using `\!`. The required infos could be written to temp files with `\o file` or `\g file`. Also the `:var` substitutions from psql might help.

Comment: @tscho In that case, you can either (a) use a more sophisticated scripting language with its own PostgreSQL interface, or (b) use a co-process to control psql from bash. See this answer I wrote to a very similar question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/398670

Comment: @CraigRinger: thanks for your comment, I will take a look into that. For now I am stuck to bash (I'd quit if I was stuck to windows, though ;) and I'm currently not looking for a production grade solution, it's more of a proof of concept.